# Why can't we have only one complex eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be matrix. If $bi$ ($b$ is real) is eigenvalue then $-bi$ is also eigenvalue. Why can it alone exist? $bi$ is eigenvalue and $-bi$ is not eigenvalue.

My attempt at proving this:
[eigenvalues are roots of characteristic equation. Any equation, complex roots exist in pair. But how to prove this?]

$Ax = bi x$ and say $$Ax \neq -bix \\ \implies Ax \neq -bix = - Ax \\ 2Ax \neq0  $$

It should lead to contradiction somehow. I could not see it.

Also $Ax \neq -bix, bix =Ax \neq -bix \implies 2bix \neq 0$ it should be possible right say of x = [1,2] then $bix = bi(1+2) $\neq$ 0 fine right?

Please help me in understanding this silly doubt

Comment: In the real case, the characteristic polynomial can only have conjugate roots.

Comment: Terminology nit-pick: Complex doesn't really mean non-real. So we _can_ have only one complex eigenvalue, assuming it is real. Many people (including me some times), when they say "complex" mean "complex and not real", but that's not quite right.

Comment: Just to emphasize what was said in the answer, if you're talking about matrices with complex entries, all bets are off. In particular, you can look at the diagonal matrices $\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -3i\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Don't edit to make it wrong, please. The OP is talking about the pure imaginary $bi$. I have removed your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a real matrix,

$$Ax=bx$$ implies by conjugation

$$Ax^*=b^*x^*$$

and $b^*$ is an Eigenvalue.

---

In the complex case, you can set the Eigenvalues that you want in a diagonal matrix (it can be simply $\begin{bmatrix}i\end{bmatrix}$ !).

Comment: this is easy to understand. Thank you.. But If A has complex entries then there can exist only 1 complex eigen value right? (please correct me if wrong)

Comment: @NascimentodeCos: a diagonal matrix will have the Eigenvalues that you want.

Comment: this is too good sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is true if your matrix has real entries. As you said, eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial $f(x)$, which will have real coefficients. The [conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem) then gives you what you need.

Comment: Sir kindly elaborate in lay man terms. If matrix has real entries, then its eigen values can have only 1 of 2 conjugate complex values. If matrix has complex entries, then it has to exist in pairs?(please correct me if i am wrong here) Any easy way to prove this? Else i will go thru conjugate root theorem

Comment: Eigenvalues of your matrix are exactly the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. So we have reduced your problem to showing that if $f(x)$ is a real polynomial and $bi$ is a root of $f(x)$ (i.e. an eigenvalue of your matrix), then $-bi$ is also a root of $f(x)$ (i.e. another eigenvalue of your matrix). This is exactly what the conjugate root theorem proves.

Comment: understood sir. Also went thru proof of conjugate root theorem. It was easy to understand. If a matrix has real values then if there is complex root then it has to exist in pairs(please correct me if wrong). If matrix has complex entries, then it becomes characteristic equation with coefficients as complex values. In that case, can only 1 complex eigen value exist? if so how does it look like?

Comment: If the entries of the matrix are complex, the eigenvalues can be any complex numbers. (Take the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to whatever eigenvalues you want.)

Answer (score 0):

For real matrix we always have complex conjugate eigenvalues. Indeed recall that for a real matrix the trace is real and the trace is equal to the sum of eigenvalues.

Otherwise it is not necessarly the case.

Comment: Not really a proof, may have a $4 \times 4$ real matrix with real trace but all different imaginary parts which cancel out...